# add behavior extension to endpoint behaviour in code

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I add behavior extension in web.config:

```
<extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="WebAppBeaviourElement" type="WebApp.Extensions.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, WebApp.Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebAppBeaviour">
                <WebAppBeaviourElement />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

But in Visual Studio 2010 is bug - WebAppBehaviourElement is not visible by visual studio and get error:/

So I think that it is possible to add this extension to endpointBehaviours in code ? And when in code I should do it?

Comment: What error did you get? Why do you think it is a bug? Extensions are only for configuration file. If you want to add behavior in code you will do it directly on endpoint.

Comment: I dont't remember it , but error said something like WebAppBeaviourElement can not be set as element of behaviour

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the host factory

`public class ExtendedHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory`

Then, add behavior to the host

```
protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(System.Type serviceType, System.Uri[] baseAddresses)
  {
    ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses) as WebServiceHost;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ValidateApiKey()); // ValidateApiKey is an IServiceBehavior
  }
```

You can add the host in config. If you choose code for that too, add it in global.asax as below

```
ExtendedHostFactory factory = new ExtendedHostFactory();
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(@"myservice/path", factory, typeof(MyService)));
```

Comment: you forgot to add return section into overrided method, but it was obviously) helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 validate configuration file against XSD schemas.
One is defined for here [**system.serviceModel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731734.aspx) There is no yours custom behavior, but programms work.

Comment: this is the issue i have http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/386511/custom-wcf-behavior-extension-element-type-not-found-during-design-time